# Show that Wiener process with drift is a Levy process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, levy-processes

Hey I have to check if process $X_t=\mu t+\sigma W_t$ is a Levy process where $W_t$ is a Wiener process and $\sigma>0,\mu\in\mathbb{R}$. First, $X_0=0$ so it is ok. Then, for $s<t$ we have $X_t-X_s=\mu(t-s)+\sigma(W_t-W_s)\sim N(\mu(t-s),\sigma(t-s))$ so $X_t-X_s$ has the same distribution as $X_{t-s}$. Now I take $0<u<v<s<t$ and we have that $X_v-X_u=\mu(v-u)+\sigma(W_v-W_u)$ and $X_t-X_s=\mu(t-s)+\sigma(W_t-W_s)$ so they are independent since $W_v-W_u$ and $W_t-W_s$ are independent. Now I have to check that $X_t$ is stochastic continuity. This condition states that
$$\lim_{s\to t}P(|X_s-X_t|>\epsilon)=0$$
Can anyone show me how to chech this condition?

EDIT: I try sth like this:
$$P(|X_s-X_t|>\epsilon)=1-P(|\mu(s-t)+\sigma(W_s-W_t)|\le \epsilon)$$
$$=1-P(|\mu(t-s)+\sigma W_{t-s}|\le \epsilon)=1-P(-\epsilon\le\mu(t-s)+\sigma\sqrt{t-s}W_1\le \epsilon)$$
$$=1-P(\frac{-\epsilon-\mu(t-s)}{\sigma\sqrt{t-s}}\le W_1\le \frac{\epsilon-\mu(t-s)}{\sigma\sqrt{t-s}})=$$
$$=1-\Phi(\frac{\epsilon-\mu(t-s)}{\sigma\sqrt{t-s}})+\Phi(\frac{-\epsilon-\mu(t-s)}{\sigma\sqrt{t-s}})$$
And now I have to take limit as $s\to t$ but because there is square root, the limit can be only one sided.

Comment: Just write down $X_s-X_t$ using the definition of $X_s$, and use the stochastic continuity of the Wiener process. Do you get stuck while doing this?

Comment: I try to do this by calculating this probability and taking the limit but I have a problem (I edit my question)

Comment: The problem is that $W_t - W_s$ is not $W_{t-s}$ unless $t>s$. So you need to assume that $t>s$ then do it, and then assume $t<s$ and do it (and show that these cases cover the whole limit situation, which is quite trivial).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$1-\Phi\left(\frac{\epsilon-\mu(t-s)}{\sigma\sqrt{t-s}}\right)+\Phi\left(\frac{-\epsilon-\mu(t-s)}{\sigma\sqrt{t-s}}\right)$$ is equivalent to $$1-\Phi\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sigma\sqrt{t-s}}-\frac\mu\sigma\sqrt{t-s}\right)+\Phi\left(\frac{-\epsilon}{\sigma\sqrt{t-s}}-\frac\mu\sigma\sqrt{t-s}\right)$$ so we have $$\lim_{s\to t^-}P(|X_s-X_t|>\epsilon)=1-\Phi(+\infty)+\Phi(-\infty)=1-1+0=0.$$ It does not matter that the limit is one-sided as WLOG you set $s<t$, similar calculations hold when you set $s>t$.